# show that $E(X|G)=\int_0^{\infty}P[X>t|G]dt$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

For $0\le X \in L_1$,  $X$ is a random variable on $(\Omega,B,P)$, and G is a $\sigma$-algebra and $G \subset B$, show almost surely
$$E(X|G)=\int_0^{\infty}P[X>t|G]dt$$
Here is my try:
This is about conditional expectation. By the definition of the conditional expectation $E(X|G)$ has two requirements:
$$E(X|G) \in G$$ 
And for all  $ A \in G$
$$\int_AE(X|G)dP=\int_AXdP $$
It's easy to get the second equation. That is 
$$
\begin{align}
\int_A\int_0^\infty P[X>t|G]dtdP &= \int_0^\infty \int_A P[X>t|G]dPdt \;\;(Fubini) \\ 
&= \int_0^\infty \int_A E(1_{[X>t]}|G)dPdt 
\\&=\int_0^\infty \int_{A} 1_{[X>t]}dPdt
\\&=\int_{A} \int_0^\infty  1_{[X>t]}dtdP \;\; (Fubini)
\\&=\int_A X dP
\end{align}
$$

But I tried a lot, still cannot prove the first one, because it's contained in the integral. Anyone has any idea? Thank you!

Comment: $G$ is not just any subset of $B$, it's a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Do you know how to prove the analogous statement for unconditional expectation?

Comment: Also, your definition of conditional expectation is not right.  It isn't sufficient to show that $E(E(X|G)) = E(X)$, you have to show that for any $A \in G$ we have $E(1_A E(X | G)) = E(1_A X)$.

Comment: Shouldn't your first issue not be proving an equality involving the RHS, but seeing that it makes sense?  It is not obvious to me that it makes sense.  For each t, the integrand is only defined up to a set of $P$ measure 0.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have fixed it. I know how to prove the unconditional version. For the vagueness, I think it makes sense. Because $P[X>t|G]$ can be written as $E(1_{[X>t]}|G)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t,\omega) = E[\mathbb{1}_{X>t}|\mathcal{G}](\omega)$, we are going to prove the $\mathcal{G}$-measurability of $g_a(\omega) = \int_{0}^{a}f(t,\omega)dt, \forall a>0$. Then $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(t,\omega)dt = \lim_{a\rightarrow +\infty}g_a(\omega)$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

Firstly since $f(t,\omega)$ is monotone for t, it is Riemann integrable. So $\int_{0}^{a}f(t,\omega)dt = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(a\frac{k}{n}, \omega)\frac{a}{n}$. Note that for a fixed $t$, $f(t,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, so the finite sum is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, and then their limit(we know it exists) is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Thus we have proven the $G$-measurability of $g_a(\omega)$

Comment: Btw, I am wondering if $f(t, \omega)$ is dt-measurable for a fixed $\omega$ and if $f(t, \omega)$ itself is $dt \otimes \mathcal{G}$-measurable.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense! Thank you very much!

Comment: If $f(t,\omega)$ is defined on $(B,B(\mathbb{R}))$, I think so. The conditional expectation $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ is the smoothing of $X$. Then $E(1_{[X>t]}|\mathcal{G})(\omega)$ is something like $a1_{[X(\omega)>t]}$, where $a<1$

Comment: "since f(t,ω) is monotone for t" This may very well be true **for no omega at all**.

Comment: @Did: Sorry, I don't understand very well. Could you give a little more explanation? What I think is if $t >s$, then $\mathbb{1}_{X > t} \leq \mathbb{1}_{X > s}$, thus their conditional expectations follow the same order. Is it wrong?

Comment: This would require to define simultaneously all these conditionings. Recall that, for each $t$, $P[X\gt t\mid G]$ is only defined up to a negiligible set.

Comment: @Did:You are right, I really forget this point. For a fixed $\omega$, $f(t, \omega)$ is not well-defined. Maybe the arguments can be saved by beginning with $t \in Q^+$ then take limits? I will think about it. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed an argument based on the density of Q and the ordering of R is the usual way to save this construction.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the question is not well formulated but here is my answer to what I think is being asked assuming the conditional PDF exists:
$$\int_0^{z} x f(x|G)\,dx=\left.x\cdot F(x|G)\right|_0^z-\int_0^{z} F(x|G)\,dx=$$
$$ =\int_0^{z} (F(z|G)-F(x|G))dx$$ now take $z\rightarrow \infty$ to get $E[X|G]$.
Notice the convergence is monotone.

Comment: Thank you! I have revised it, please see it again!

Comment: @abc1m2x3c : if you have $\int_A Y dP=\int_A X dP$ for all $A\in G$ then $Y$ is a version of $E[X|G]$ so I think you already proved it in your own answer.

Comment: I very much dislike that sometimes the conditional expectation notation is used to denote the regular condition distribution, as you guess here.  But it was also my guess for what the question was asking, given that the literal way it's phrased doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SergioParreiras: Maybe I didn't get your point, but $\int_{A}X dP = \int_{A} X dP, \forall A \in \mathcal{G}$ is always true while we can't say $X$ is equal to $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ almost surely

Comment: @Liu Gang: you are right, I forgot to write $Y$ is $G$-measurable and in his case $1-F[X<t|G]$ is measurable so it seems he answered the question himself.